# why no libatomic after i compile the gcc-4.7.4

Tags: gcc

I compiled my gcc. Everything is OK .but there is no `libatomic.so`.
my configure is :

```
"../configure 
--prefix=/repo/zling003/my/usr/gcc_4_7 
--build=i386-linux-gnu 
--with-mpfr=/repo/zling003/my/usr/gcc_4_7 
--with-gmp=/repo/zling003/my/usr/gcc_4_7 
--with-mpc=/repo/zling003/my/usr/gcc_4_7 
--enable-checking=release
--enable-languages=c,c++  
--program-suffix=-4.7"
```

how to let GCC support libatomic.so ?

Comment: I would first try a less ancient version...

Comment: i have compiled GCC 5.4 and GCC 4.9 .There is other error:

Comment: /usr/include/sys/timex.h:145:31: error: expected initializer before throw
      __asm__ ("ntp_gettimex") __THROW;

Comment: This is Redhat bugs,i have fixed it by below workround:
./configure --prefix=/home/gz/apps/gcc-4.9.3 --enable-languages=c,c++ \
    --disable-multilib --disable-libsanitizer --disable-libcilkrts